# Как в jQuery UI Slider узнать в какую сторону смещается ползунок?

Tags: jquery-ui

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в jQuery UI Slider получить направление (увеличение или уменьшение) смещения ползунка.
В зависимости от направления, например, изменять размер блока.

Answer (score 1):

Используем событие slide (исполняется при каждом перемещении слайдера) и сравниваем предыдущее значение слайдера с текущим. В комментариях есть подробное объяснение. Спасибо @Qwertiy за помощь.

HTML:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<p id="result"></p>
```

JS:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    slide: function(ev,ui) {
            var prev = $(this).slider('value'),
                curr = ui.value;

            if(prev < curr) {
                $('#result').html('&uarr;');  
            } else {
                $('#result').html('&darr;');  
            }
        }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ytjbnary/

Comment: Это действительно то что требуется? Он определяет направление перемещения безотносительно выбранного значения, что мне кажется неверным. Если брать текущее значение слайдера и не химичить с сохранением из slide, то будет именно относительно выбранного значения.

Comment: Хм.. Я не прав, текущее значение слайдара содержит как раз предыдущее значение. `var prev = $(this).slider('value'), cur = ui.value;` - работает так же, как твой вариант, только без лишних сохранений. https://jsfiddle.net/s36u0kub/2/

Comment: Да, видимо, события выстреливаются так: start -> slide (тут мы сравниваем значения) -> stop (тут устанавливается новый value), поэтому можно и так.

Comment: Отметь как "ответ".

Comment: Как отметить как ответ?

Comment: Рядом с голосовалкой за ответ (вверх-вниз) должна быть галочка. Нажать, станет зеленой, другие сразу увидят, что этот ответ работает, я получу сколько-то там в карму.

Comment: Убери data-аттрибут (с которым ты ещё и через attr работаешь вместо data) - тогда да. А так мне ответ не нравится, хотя да, он работает. Но вообще, есть подозрение, что спрашивающий ожидает другого поведения - когда точкой отсчёта является подтверждённое значение, а не предыдущее значение на слайдере.

Comment: А, так это не твой вопрос. Я не заметил. Понятно, почему ты "ответом" не можешь пометить :) Про data - согласен. Хотя $elem.data(attr, value) работает МЕДЛЕННЕЕ, чем $elem.attr(attr,value), что забавно. А вот $.data(elem, attr, value) работает буквально на порядок быстрее.

Сейчас код оптимизирую.

Comment: Держи плюсик :) Про data - возможно, оно медленнее attr потому что jQuery связывает свой кэш с элементом, т. е. хранить можно любой объект, а не только строку. А attr просто мапится на атрибуты.